# How can I restore Chrome Customize fonts to the default?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, fonts

(I'm using a MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019) Monterey v12.5)

I was trying to test different font settings and I came up messing my "Fixed-width font".

The default is "Custom" and once I changed it to other fonts it just disappears in the drop-down list.
I figured out "Custom" font should be Courier New with bold font weight.

I have been googling to see if there is any way to restore it to the default but not quite getting the answer.

Reinstalling Chrome might be one of the methods but it takes me long time to restore other settings. I would like to know if there is other way before trying reinstall.

[default fixed-width font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nub18.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the way to solve my own problem.

What I've done is:

1. "Inspect" the drop-down list option
2. Change the element DOM "Courier New" -> "Courier"
3. Select any other font once and change back to Courier (that has been just changed from "Courier")

The original font should come back.
Hope this help someone who has the same problem as mine.

Comment: The answer could be improved by some clarifications: a) before step 1, the user should open up Chrome Settings page and go to Appearance, b) the "drop-down list option" refers to the actual dropdown on that page, for "Fixed width font", c) what should be changed is the text inside of the `<option>` tag, d) that text should be changed to anything not being an actual installed font name - activating the option resets the setting.